# Restore Oracle database backup from Windows 2000 server to Linux

Tags: oracle

I'm currently using Oracle 11g on Windows 2000 Server.
I make a full database backup (e.g. backup database plus archivelog) and I want to restore this backup on Linux.
What are the appropriate steps to restore this backup to Linux?

Note: I have configured controlfile autobackup on;

Best Regards,

Sarith

Comment: Sarith, I know you have accepted an answer but is your system using ASM, Managed file names or provied manually. I have done this the otherway without any archivelogs for a test system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. If your windows system is dead, you'll need to restore to another windows system. From there you must migrate your database using Oracle utilities:

Metalink indicates the following:

There is no Migration utility (Script or DBUA) to perform a cross platform migration.

To change platforms require the database instance be re-built and / or the data moved using one of the following methods:

1. Export / Import to include the use of Datapump facilities. all versions support Export/Import but for Datapump 10.1.0.2 or higher is required
2. Transportable Tablespaces 10G or Later
3. RMAN Convert Database functions. 10G or Later

The choices available will depend on BOTH the OS and Oracle versions of both the source and destination.

For example RMAN Convert Database only works if both source and destination belong to same ENDIAN format.

Transportable Tablespaces has a convert function to convert from one ENDIAN format to another.

HTH.

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14191/dbxptrn.htm for an RMAN/transportable tablespaces guide.

Comment: Lots of good info in that link.

Comment: Be careful about CLOBs/BLOBs, if you have them!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a db link from the new Linux Oracle server to the existing Windows Oracle server.  Then, you can create the schema and copy the data over the data link.

Comment: export/import (including datapump) does this faster and doesn't miss anything like constratints, triggers, indexes, synonyms, grants, etc.